# Ajax responses are getting mixed up even though use of Jquery's Ajax done

Tags: jquery

On click of a Reject Button i am calling function as shown below

```
       function reject(message, document_id, status) {
     var ajaxdo = $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: url + '/OMS/admin/UpdateAdminCategory?document_id=' + document_id + '&message=' + message + '&status=' + status,
         jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         jsonp: false,
         success: function(response) {
         },
         error: function(e) {
             alert('Error inside Fill form request');
         }
     });

     ajaxdo.done(function() {
         finalcall();
     });
 }



 function finalcall() {
     var vendor_brand_id = $('#BrandNames').val();
     $("#textandsavediv").hide();
     showT1(vendor_brand_id, '');
 }


 function showT1(vendor_brand_id, t1categorytext) {
     var ajaxq = $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: url + '/OMS/admin/categorylevelservice?vendor_brand_id=' + vendor_brand_id + '&reqstr=' + t1categorytext,
         jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         jsonp: false,
         beforeSend: function() {
             $('#T1').html('<img src="input-spinner.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
         },
         success: function(response) {
             displayT1(response, t1categorytext)
         },
         error: function(e) {
             alert('Error inside Fill form request');
         }
     });

 }

 function displayT1(response, t1categorytext) {
     $("#T1").append(html);
 }
```

The issue i am facing is that the Ajax responses are getting mixed up

Please tell me how to resolve this ?

Comment: Curly braces are out of balance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that , its a typo error . I edited my code .

Comment: Still doesn't look right

Comment: Where does that `html` variable in the displayT1 function come from?

Comment: From  the response i construct the html and append to it , i didn't posted it purposefully as it is bigger and adds confusion .

Answer (score 0):

Straightening everything out and making appropriate returns, I end up with this, which may fix the problem :

```
function reject(message, document_id, status) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/OMS/admin/UpdateAdminCategory',
        data: {
            'message': message, 
            'document_id': document_id, 
            'status': status
        },
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false
    }).then(function(response) {
        $(".saveclassbtn").hide();
        var vendor_brand_id = $('#BrandNames').val();
        $("#textandsavediv").hide();
        return showT1(vendor_brand_id, '');
    }).then(null, function(e) {
        console.log('Error inside Fill form request');
        return e;
    });
}

function showT1(vendor_brand_id, t1categorytext) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/OMS/admin/categorylevelservice',
        data: {
            'vendor_brand_id': vendor_brand_id,
            'reqstr': t1categorytext
        },
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#T1').html('<img src="input-spinner.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        // Process data and set data 
        $("#T1").append(html);
    }).then(null, function(e) {
        console.log('Error inside Fill form request');
        return e;
    });
}
```

Call as follows :

```
reject(...).then(function() {
    //do whatever on overall completion
}).fail(function(e) {
    console.Error(e);
});
```